# what happens to after trigger actions, when a table fails in insert actions that trigger these trigger functions?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I insert a row into a table X, then it will trigger another trigger function to insert a row into another table Y.

But if the first insert fails, then what happens to the other trigger functions?
Do these trigger functions work or not?
I want to ask this for before trigger too?
If the before trigger on X table fails while inserting a row into table Y, then does the  insert into table X work or not?

Comment: Triggers are highly product specific. Please edit your question and add a tag for your database system (e.g. [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], etc.)

Comment: ok sure, i added postgresql tag...

Answer (score 1):

Anything the trigger does runs in the same transaction as the statement that caused the trigger to fire. If the "calling transaction" gets rolled back, so does any change done by the trigger.

Comment: thank you for reply...what about another situation like we use before trigger on X table(that will insert row into Y table before insert into X table) and after that there would be an insert on X table  ; what if before trigger that will insert row into Y table fails, would inserting action into X table still be applied even if before trigger fails?

Comment: The first error will abort the transaction and will prevent any subsequent triggers to fire.

Comment: well if i get it right, "triggers" and "actions (like insert actions) that trigger trigger functions which are defined on this table" are all considered in the same transaction...If one fails then all fail.